# Choice between Autowired and using static field

Tags: spring, static, field, autowired

I have a single configuration bean that has the app's configuration settings. I want to expose this bean to any java class in my application. Do i autowire it to every class that need the bean or do i set it to a static field in some global class to make it conveniently accessible to every class? Is autowiring reasonable/recommended for high turnover objects? In my case this would be some network events coming in multiples every second.

Comment: You cannot `@Autowired` static fields. I suggest you inject it as an instance of every class that needs it. (Technically you can hack it, but don't.)

Comment: I agree with @Sotirious Delimanolis. Let the spring singletons to manage your instances and create it when it's necessary.

Comment: even for high volume objects? Do you guys know the cost of @Autowired? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach with AspectJ compile-time (or load-time) weaving:

```
public final class Config {

    public static String oneParticularSetting() {
        return new ConfigHolder().oneParticularSetting;
    }

    @Configurable
    private static class ConfigHolder {
        @Value("${oneParticularSetting}")
        private String oneParticularSetting;
    }
}
```

Autowiring overhead/performance is something you'll just have to test.

Or you could reuse the ConfigHolder instance (taking thread safety into consideration).